# How to login onto cognos 8.4 bi using a simple php script?

Tags: php, authentication, iis-6, cognos-bi

**Current state:**

- I have cognos 8.4 bi running on a iis 6 and it runs authentication on openldap.
- I have a script written in php which also can authenticate using this openldap.

**Aim:**

Use only the php script for login-purpose and then send the user/pass forward to cognos.

**Question:**

How to forward login-data or how to login onto a cognos using a php script?